# Fibonacci Number Equals to The number of compositions of n+2 using integers $\ge2$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

My textbook provides following task -

Prove combinatorially following statement :

**The number of compositions of $n+2$ using integers $\ge2$ is a Fibonacci number**

---

So I had tried first several few numbers :

(1) if $n = 0$, $n+2 =2$ and it only gives $1$ cases such as $\{2\}$

(2) if $n =1$, $n+2 = 3$ and it only gives $1$ cases such as $\{2,1\}$

(3) if $n =2$, $n+2 = 4$ and it gives $2$ cases such as $\{2,2\}$ and $\{4\}$

(4) if $n =3$, $n+2 = 5$ and it gives 2 cases such as $\{5\}$ , $\{3,2\}$

so till now the sequence I got is $1, 1, 2, 2$ which is obviously deviated from Fibonacci Sequence.

---

Is there anything I missed or the problem set wrong or any modification required to make the problem set complete?

Comment: 1 and 2 are Fibonacci number, so it seems fine. It does not say that the numbers are not repeated or skipped. That would be a different assertion

Comment: @ZachBoyd got it.. I just arbitrarily misunderstand the intention of pb. thx.

Comment: @ZachBoyd but in case of n = 5 which n+2 = 7, there exist four - {7} {5,2} {3,2,2} {3,4}- which is not Fibonacci number.

Comment: Hm interesting. Someone with more number theory experience than me may need to look at it in that case.

Comment: @ZachBoyd Thx for your valuable consideration!

Comment: For $(2)$ the composition of $3$ is $3$, not $2,1$ because $1$ is not allowed, but there is still $1$ of them.  For $(4)$ you are missing the point that compositions depend on order, so $(2,3)$ is different from $(3,2)$ and there are $3$ of them, which is a Fibonacci number.  Then for $n=5$ there are $8$ of them if you count order.

Comment: @RossMillikan now it makes sense the order matters then it comprises the Fibo-nums

Comment: @RossMillikan Any hint to prove this, how are the Fibonacci Numbers are characterized?

Comment: Actually on reflecting further, isn't it the case that 5,2 and 2,5 should be counted separately in this context, i.e. Order dies matter? In that case you get 8 ways, which is a Fibonacci number.

Comment: @ZachBoyd:  that is why the problem specifies compositions instead of partitions.  Compositions care about order, partitions do not.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(n)$ be the number of compositions of $n$ with parts at least $2$.  To find a composition of $n$ into parts of at least $2$ you can either start with a composition of $n-1$ and add $1$ to the last part or you can start with a composition of $n-2$ and append a new part of $2$ at the end.  You have to convince yourself that you have not double counted any compositions.  This gives $A(n)=A(n-1)+A(n-2)$ which is the Fibonacci recurrence.  Once you have two terms that match the Fibonacci sequence, all the rest will.  We have enough hand calculation for the first few terms.

Comment: For the first case not to add 1 any of the part but always add 1 to end element of each case of A (n-1)